# Best way to add different colours based on conditions to bargraphs plotted with Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, python, graph, highcharts, flask

I have a simple, Flask application that generates a series of sparkling bargraphs with Highcharts.js into a HTML table. I have adapted the example code of Highcharts' webpage to generate my page. Basically my plotting function is identical to the documentation, with small modifications

```
function doChunk() {
    var time = +new Date(),
        i,
        len = $tds.length,
        $td,
        stringdata,
        arr,
        data,
        chart;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        $td = $($tds[i]);
        stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
        data = $.map(stringdata, parseFloat);
        chart = {};
        chart.type= 'column';
        $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
                data: data,
                pointStart: 1,
            }],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 12px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Amplicon {point.x}:</span><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
            chart: chart
        });

        n += 1;

        // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
        if (new Date() - time > 500) {
            $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
doChunk();

});
```

The Flask module reads an ASCII file, does some processing and sends to the HTML portion of the template the values that then sent for plotting. All the values passed to the data-sparkline objects are lists

```
      {% for gene in gene_information %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ gene }}</th>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ gene_information[gene]['total_length'] }}</td>
        <td data-sparkline="{{ gene_information[gene]['min_coverage'] | string }}"/>
        <td data-sparkline="{{ gene_information[gene]['target_perc'] }}"/>
        <td data-sparkline="{{ gene_information[gene]['above_30'] }}">
        <td data-sparkline="{{ gene_information[gene]['zero'] }}">
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Now, what would be the most straightforward way to set a condition to the bar colour based on the value provided by Flask? Let's say I want to make the default bar colour blue, but if one the 'above_30' list values is below 50 the bar turns red?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could possibly make use of the zones property?  | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones

Comment: Seems a good idea. I will try to implement, thanks a lot for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jlbriggs comment, I was able to find the right solution. I have tried adding a zone to the options section of the Sparkline function but that didn't work. The zone section had to be added to the doChunk() function of when the series of value is created, as a parameter for the Highcharts.Sparkline function

```
$td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
                data: data,
                pointStart: 1,
                zoneAxis: 'y',
                zones: [{
                    value: 99,
                 color: '#FF1811'
            }],
            }],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 12px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Amplicon {point.x}:</span><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
            chart: chart
        });
```

It still a little bit hard top control different graphs colours, but at least the effect I was looking for was set.